# Finding parents/siblings of Pietro Bracchetti who lived in Ala, Trent,Tirol, Austria around 1678?

Tags: 17th-century, austria

I am researching Pietro Bracchetti who lived in Ala, Trent, Tirol, Austria around 1678:

- He was born in Lemma.
- He traveled to Ala because he was the architect that worked at the construction of the Parish on that place.

How can I find his parents and/or siblings?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take our [tour] which introduces you to the differences between our focussed Q&A format that is different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites which you may have used.  I'll edit your question to try and focus it a little, and then probably add some comments on other ways that I think you can use to improve it to help attract potential answerers.

Comment: Are you able to [edit] your question to include information like whether you have found his birth record (which should mention his father), or perhaps a will (which may mention his wife, siblings, nieces/nephews), please?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  It is useful if you can say briefly what sources you have looked at already, and how you know the information that you have in your question.